# What operands expect modulo % operator?

Tags: c++

From the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Multiplicative_operators), the modulo operator's prototype is said to be `T T::operator%(const T2 &b) const;` from inside class definition and `T operator%(const T &a, const T2 &b);` outside class definition. I don't know if here is where i need to look for an answer to my question.

My questions raised from this example:

```
int i = 2;
float f = 4.4;

cout << f % float(i);      // ERROR
```

So:

1. what operands type does modulo expects (`int`? if so, where does it write in cppreference?)
2. shouldn't `f` variable be converted to `int` as a conversion? The error received was `invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float' to binary 'operator%'`. I was expecting to be invalid operands of type `int` and `float`.

Comment: integral not float or double.

Comment: The `operator%` syntax is used only for *overloaded* operators. Builtin operators (for builtin types) don't use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the very page you cite:

> 3) remainder: For the built-in operator, `lhs` and `rhs` must both have integral or unscoped enumeration type

If you are in need of computing a floating point remainder, there's [`fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod)

Comment: i dont see were u cited from

Comment: Click the link in your post, press `Ctrl+F`, search for "remainder"

Comment: Thank you, could you please tell me whether there is no conversion happening? Like if there is not an integral type there will be an error, no implicit conversion, right?

Comment: Why don't you write a simple test program and see for yourself?